# Prevent video frame rate changes when recording HTML5 video using getUserMedia in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm recording video in the browser using [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder). The following was tested with all permutations of OSX 10.11.1, Windows 10, Firefox 41 and Chrome 46.

Basically every second the recorded video is transferred to a server using HTTP POST. This second-wise notification arrives via ondataavailable event of MSR.

It works well in Firefox but produces the following (undesired) behavior in Chrome: When the tab that runs this code is in the background (or the window is not visible because it is occluded by another window), frame rate drops to zero and only empty-hull webms are produced every second. When I bring the window/tab back to front it starts transmitting video blobs containing frames (with variable frame rate) again.

I tried setting the frame rate specifically in the video contraints without success (the setting is handled via [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) to be compatible).

I tried not displaying the video but only recording it (the code below does not contain any video display functionality) without success.

What can I do to produce frames even when the tab is not visible in Chrome?

Here the code:

```
function userMedia() {
    return navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia || null;
}

function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    startRecording(stream, handleBlob);
}

function onMediaError(error) {
    alert('Error opening user media: ' + error);
}

/**
 * Initializes the media recording functionality, asks for rights for webcam access.
 */
function init() {
    var constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
            frameRate: 20
        }
    };

    if (userMedia()) {
        navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);
    } else {
        alert('No access to user media sources supported.');
    }
};

function handleBlob(blob) {
    console.log('Sending', blob.size, 'bytes');

    // ... send to server ...
}

function startRecording(stream, handleBlob) {
    console.log('Starting recording.');
    mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'video/webm';
    mediaRecorder.width = 640;
    mediaRecorder.height = 480;

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
        handleBlob(blob);
    };

    mediaRecorder.start(1000); // generates ondataavailable events
    console.log('Recording started.');
}
```

Comment: This feature is very much a work in progress in Chrome. I suggest you write a comment here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=262211

Comment: Thanks! That issue is very informative. I don't have the rights to comment on it, but I'll try to contact the people there.

Comment: I can't comment either. Nor can I get this feature to work, even with flag enabled. Are you using Chromium or Canary? Mac/Win/Linux?

Comment: As denoted above: Chrome on OSX El Capitan/Win10.

Comment: I 'solved' this issue by putting the video recording element in an iframe instead of a separate tab. This works, but the 'solution' may by only applicable in my current use case and not a general one.