# Clear stored video in MediaStreamRecorder after ondataavailable while still recording?

Tags: html, webrtc, getusermedia

When I'm recording video in the browser using MediaStreamRecorder (OSX 10.11.1/Windows 10, Firefox 41/Chrome 46) I get out of memory errors (MacBook Air, 4GB RAM) in Firefox after half an hour of recording, even though I'm handling the data every second within the ondataavailable event (See my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354918/prevent-video-frame-rate-changes-when-recording-html5-video-using-getusermedia-i) for details and code). Chrome works for more than an hour, but it too has increasing memory usage over time.

I suppose the browser is not discarding the recorded video after the event (which usually makes sense, I never told it to discard any video data). Is there any way I can trigger a cleanup? I'm not interested in video data after the event.

Comment: Do you use `delete`?

Comment: Could you show some code? It's possible you're doing something to cause it to prevent garbage collection inadvertently.

Comment: may be you are looking at the issue from the wrong angle, how fast are the files getting stored in the server, may be because of that bottleneck of low bandwidth, files get queued up and you eventually run out of memory...

Answer (score 1):

[Check this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8upv28ok)

You can clear by stopping mediaRecorder stream tracks as below

```
stream
    .getTracks()
    .forEach( track => track.stop() );
```

Comment: You should try using StackOverflow's built-in Code Snippets instead of JSFiddle: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/
They allow the code to be viewed directly on this page instead of having to link out to JSFiddle

Comment: This is my first answer at Stackoverflow. I am learni how to answer and use features of stackoverflow.